# Does $2\int_{0}^{y^{2}}c(t)\,dt<3\frac{1}{y}\int_{0}^{y^{2}}\sqrt{t}c(t)\,dt$ always hold for positive and increasing $c(t)$?

Tags: functions

I come across one problem. Does $2\int_{0}^{y^{2}}c(t)\,dt<3\frac{1}{y}\int_{0}^{y^{2}}\sqrt{t}c(t)\,dt$ always hold ? The $y$ is any positive number. The domain of $c(t)$ is $[0,\infty)$ and it is smooth, strictly increasing the positive. I think it is not true. But I cannot find out one counter-example of $c(t)$. Can you help ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality is equivalent to

$$  2y \int_0^{y^2} c(t) dt \le 3 \int_0^{y^2}\sqrt{t}  c(t) dt.$$

Let's prove this by differentiation.

$$ \frac{d}{dy} \left (  2y \int_0^{y^2} c(t) dt\right)  = 2 \int_0^{y^2} c(t) dt + 4y^2 c(y^2) < 6 y^2 c(y^2),$$

because $c$ is strictly increasing. Also,

$$ \frac{d}{dy}\left (  3\int_0^{y^2} \sqrt{t} c(t) dt\right) = 6 y^2 c(y^2),$$

and result follows, because both are equal to zero at $y=0$.

Answer (score -1):

If $c(t)=1$ we have

$2\int_{0}^{y^{2}}c(t)\,dt=3\frac{1}{y}\int_{0}^{y^{2}}\sqrt{t}c(t)\,dt$

Edit: this is no counterexample since $c$ shoul be increasing

FRED

Comment: but the $c(t)$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: Pardon ! you are right